# Recurrence Relation for Divide and Conquer

Tags: algorithm

Describe the recurrence running time T(n) on an input of size n?

A divide and conquer algorithm takes an array of `n` elements and divides into three sub arrays of size `n/4` each taking `Θ(n)` time to do the subdivision. The time taken to combine outputs of each sub-problem is `Θ(1)`.

I came with this recurrence relation, but it's not correct

```
T(n) = 3T(n/4) + Θ(1)
```

Can someone knows what I am doing wrong on this?

Comment: Seems off-topic for SO, i.e. not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

You missed  `taking Θ(n) time to do the subdivision` part.
So relation should include  `subdivision + working on smaller parts + combining`

```
T(n)= Θ(n) + 3T(n/4) + Θ(1) = 3T(n/4) + Θ(n)
```